# Entity Framework 6 code-first stored procedure map to complex objects

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

How do I use a stored procedure to get a parent and its children?

A generic version of my code is this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Int32 ParentId { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentGuid { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public Int32 ChildId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class ParentMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Parent>
{
    public ParentMapping()
    {
        ToTable("Parents");
        HasKey(t => t.ParentId);
    }
}

public class ChildMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Child>
{
    public ChildMapping()
    {
        ToTable("Children");
        HasKey(t => t.ChildId);
        HasRequired(t => t.Parent).WithMany(t => t.Children);
    }
}
```

I am trying to call a stored procedure and get the parents children as well:

```
_context.Database.SqlQuery<Parent>("EXEC [dbo].[GetParent] @ParentGuid", new SqlParameter("@ParentGuid", parentGuid)).SingleOrDefault();
```

The stored procedure is a simple select:

```
SELECT 
    P.*,
    C.*
FROM 
    [dbo].[Parents] P
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[Children] C ON C.[ParentId] = P.[ParentId]
WHERE 
    P.[ParentGuid] = @ParentGuid
```

Right now, it is only mapping the Parent's data to the object. The `Children` collection is null. What do I need to do to get this populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `context.Database.SqlQuery` the entities are untracked, just returned as pure data models. If you want to resolve the children (via lazy loading) then you need to query for them in a way that also adds the objects to EF object graph:

```
_context.Set<Parent>().SqlQuery(...)
```

By running the sql query against the `DbSet` it will track them by default and the lazy-loading should now work.

Comment: Works exactly how I want it to.  Thanks!

Comment: I did run into an issue where if you have multiple children, the sproc is returning multiple rows.  So, in the code, I would normally `do _context.Set<Parent>().SqlQuery().SingleOrDefault();`  The SingleOrDefault throws an error since multiple rows are returned. Is there a way to get EF to coalesce the Parent?